# Is there a way to change a twig config for twig files in a specific bundle?

Tags: symfony

What I want to do is change the strict_variables twig configuration without changing that config for the entire application.

Comment: inject Twig in the relevant Controller methods/routes and set the config values via php. what exactly is the problem?

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned that I am trying to render the view straight from the route but the problem is that the view requires variables so it gives an error. I would need to change the strict_variables config to avoid the error but I do not want to change this config for all twigs in the application.

Comment: as you happen to ignore the jist of my comment. you can read it again ;o) alternatively, you can just fix your templates to better handle missing variables (`??` is your friend), because that's the clean thing to do.